# Json failing to parse

Tags: c#, json

I have the following JSON string coming back from an API

```
{"success":true,"data":[
{"id":6,"order_nr":1,"name":"Capture Details","active_flag":true,"deal_probability":100,"pipeline_id":2,"rotten_flag":false,"rotten_days":null,"add_time":"2022-02-09 12:22:26","update_time":"2022-03-14 12:42:16","pipeline_name":"Stove Sales","pipeline_deal_probability":true},
{"id":19,"order_nr":2,"name":"Survey","active_flag":true,"deal_probability":100,"pipeline_id":2,"rotten_flag":false,"rotten_days":null,"add_time":"2022-02-15 13:45:03","update_time":"2022-03-14 12:42:16","pipeline_name":"Stove Sales","pipeline_deal_probability":true},
{"id":9,"order_nr":3,"name":"Quote","active_flag":true,"deal_probability":100,"pipeline_id":2,"rotten_flag":false,"rotten_days":null,"add_time":"2022-02-09 12:22:26","update_time":"2022-03-14 12:42:16","pipeline_name":"Stove Sales","pipeline_deal_probability":true},
{"id":10,"order_nr":4,"name":"Deposit Paid","active_flag":true,"deal_probability":100,"pipeline_id":2,"rotten_flag":false,"rotten_days":null,"add_time":"2022-02-09 12:22:26","update_time":"2022-03-14 12:42:16","pipeline_name":"Stove Sales","pipeline_deal_probability":true},
{"id":11,"order_nr":5,"name":"Order Stove","active_flag":true,"deal_probability":100,"pipeline_id":2,"rotten_flag":false,"rotten_days":null,"add_time":"2022-02-09 12:22:26","update_time":"2022-03-14 12:42:16","pipeline_name":"Stove Sales","pipeline_deal_probability":true},
{"id":12,"order_nr":6,"name":"Contract Agreed","active_flag":true,"deal_probability":100,"pipeline_id":2,"rotten_flag":false,"rotten_days":null,"add_time":"2022-02-09 12:22:26","update_time":"2022-03-14 12:42:16","pipeline_name":"Stove Sales","pipeline_deal_probability":true},
{"id":20,"order_nr":7,"name":"Send Full Ts&Cs for reply","active_flag":true,"deal_probability":100,"pipeline_id":2,"rotten_flag":false,"rotten_days":null,"add_time":"2022-03-14 12:42:16","update_time":"2022-03-14 12:42:16","pipeline_name":"Stove Sales","pipeline_deal_probability":true},
{"id":13,"order_nr":8,"name":"Install Stove","active_flag":true,"deal_probability":100,"pipeline_id":2,"rotten_flag":false,"rotten_days":null,"add_time":"2022-02-09 12:22:26","update_time":"2022-03-14 12:42:16","pipeline_name":"Stove Sales","pipeline_deal_probability":true},
{"id":14,"order_nr":9,"name":"Send Review","active_flag":true,"deal_probability":100,"pipeline_id":2,"rotten_flag":false,"rotten_days":null,"add_time":"2022-02-09 12:22:26","update_time":"2022-03-14 12:42:16","pipeline_name":"Stove Sales","pipeline_deal_probability":true},
{"id":15,"order_nr":1,"name":"Awaiting Sweep","active_flag":true,"deal_probability":100,"pipeline_id":3,"rotten_flag":false,"rotten_days":null,"add_time":"2022-02-12 17:57:35","update_time":"2022-02-12 17:57:35","pipeline_name":"Sweeps","pipeline_deal_probability":true},
{"id":16,"order_nr":2,"name":"Sweep Booked","active_flag":true,"deal_probability":100,"pipeline_id":3,"rotten_flag":false,"rotten_days":null,"add_time":"2022-02-12 17:57:35","update_time":"2022-02-12 17:57:35","pipeline_name":"Sweeps","pipeline_deal_probability":true},
{"id":17,"order_nr":3,"name":"Sweep","active_flag":true,"deal_probability":100,"pipeline_id":3,"rotten_flag":false,"rotten_days":null,"add_time":"2022-02-12 17:57:35","update_time":"2022-02-12 17:57:35","pipeline_name":"Sweeps","pipeline_deal_probability":true},
{"id":18,"order_nr":4,"name":"Send Review","active_flag":true,"deal_probability":100,"pipeline_id":3,"rotten_flag":false,"rotten_days":null,"add_time":"2022-02-12 17:57:35","update_time":"2022-02-12 17:57:35","pipeline_name":"Sweeps","pipeline_deal_probability":true}
]}
```

Newlines added by me whilst checking the format looked OK.  My C# data class looks like this

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;

namespace PipedriveClient
{
    internal class PipedriveStage
    {
        // Root myDeserializedClass = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<Root>(myJsonResponse);
        public class Datum
        {
            public int id { get; set; }
            public int order_nr { get; set; }
            public string name { get; set; }
            public bool active_flag { get; set; }
            public int deal_probability { get; set; }
            public int pipeline_id { get; set; }
            public bool rotten_flag { get; set; }
            public object rotten_days { get; set; }
            public string add_time { get; set; }
            public string update_time { get; set; }
            public string pipeline_name { get; set; }
            public bool pipeline_deal_probability { get; set; }
        }

        public class Root
        {
            public bool success { get; set; }
            public List<Datum> data { get; set; }
        }


    }
}
```

The code trying to parse it looks like

```
    List<PipedriveStage.Root> stages;

    using (var webClient = new WebClient())
    {
        var response = webClient.DownloadString(url);
        JObject result = JObject.Parse(response);
        var data = result.SelectToken("data");
        stages = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<List<PipedriveStage.Root>>(data.ToString());
    }
```

Checking the value of response the response string returned from by webClient is identical, so I'm confident it ought to parse OK.  My class I got by using json2csharp.com and the same basic code is working fine for other returns from the same API.  I must just be missing something trivially obvious, which I'm hoping will leap out at one of you guys!

Comment: You haven't told us what error you're getting. It's not clear to me why you're parsing to a `JObject` and then converting part of that back to a string and reparsing though. It seems it would be much simpler to just parse the result directly.

Comment: Did you check if the data.ToString() returns what you would expect?

Comment: Additionally, your JSON doesn't look like it has a `data` property that has a `List<Root>` in it... I suspect you *just* want to parse `response` to a `Root`.

Comment: Also take a look at [quicktype](https://app.quicktype.io/). It translates JSON to class presentations in a lot of different languages. It can also include (de)serialization logic. Never worry about mapping JSON again!

Comment: @JochemVanHespen: The OP is already using a reasonable site to generate the classes. The mapping really isn't the problem here - if they'd used quicktype but then kept the same code (selecting the `data` token etc) then they'd have the same problem.

Comment: @JonSkeet Yeah that's my bad, i -mistakenly- assumed we were just dealing with a json string not with JToken. TBH everytime I get some JSON i just throw it in quicktype, deserialize and be done with it, No need for JObject of whatever. But I guess that's all covered in your answer :D.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Your JSON directly represents a `PipedriveStage.Root` object. For some reason you're parsing to `JObject`, selecting the `data` token (which is an array, but of `Datum`), converting that back to a string and then parsing it as if it were a `List<Root>`.

You can change your code to just:

```cs
var root = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<PipedriveStage.Root>(response);
```

(Your `stages` variable isn't useful here - you don't logically *have* multiple roots to deserialize to.)

I would also recommend:

- Changing the property names to be idiomatic C#, using `[JsonProperty]` to indicate how they're represented in JSON. That will make your C# code look more "normal". (json2csharp.com has checkboxes for "Use Pascal Case" and "Add JsonProperty Attributes" that make this trivial.)
- Using `HttpClient` instead of `WebClient`
- Avoiding nested classes unless you really need to

Comment: @JimTench: Well I'd assume that in other cases, the structure of the response doesn't match what you want to parse it to, so you need to select a part of it before parsing. I'd generally try to take the approach used here though, so you only need to parse once rather than parsing/selecting/formatting/reparsing.